# How can I use relative paths from an R Notebook in Databricks?

Tags: r, relative-path, databricks, azure-databricks

When working in `R` I usually store my functions in a folder `./R/`

To bring these functions to the workspace I resort to the `here::here()` function. For a small script my code would start like:

```
library(here)
source(here::here("R", "custom_function1.R"))
source(here::here("R", "custom_function2.R"))
```

In this way sharing the projects amongst colleagues is quite straightforward.

I'm using `Azure-Databricks Notebooks` for a project. When using `here::here()` the function points to the server.

Is there a way to define relative paths in the `Azure-Databricks Notebooks` to keep functions decoupled from the Notebook itself?

Comment: I'm more experienced with ***PySpark*** than ***SparkR***, but everything I found seems to indicate that you need to install the packages to the cluster first, either via the GUI or with a script. Maybe [this link](https://medium.com/data-ml-engineering-with-databricks/custom-libraries-in-databricks-a-sparkr-example-with-lightgbm-2f70bfeeddd8) can help?

Comment: @SkippyNBS the link is interesting. However, it seems like an overkill if there are not many custom functions. In my case, for instance, I only use two custom functions to crawl an API; the heavy load is run later in `Spark`. Another thing I'm curious about is how to keep the version control for the tarballs in  `Azure DevOps`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am reading your problem correctly you can use relative paths.

Caveat: I am not sure however if you are looking for an equivalent to `here` library. I have not seen an equivalent to that but relative paths do work.

See:

https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/notebooks/notebook-use.html#link-to-other-notebooks

### Run a notebook from another notebook

You can run a notebook from another notebook by using the `%run <notebook>` magic command. This is roughly equivalent to a :load command in a Scala REPL on your local machine or an import statement in Python. All variables defined in  become available in your current notebook.

%run must be in a cell by itself, because it runs the entire notebook inline.

> Note You cannot use %run to run a Python file and import the entities
>   defined in that file into a notebook. To import from a Python file you
>   must package the file into a Python library, create an Azure
>   Databricks [library](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/libraries.html#libraries) from that Python library, and [install the library
>   into the cluster](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/libraries.html#install-libraries) you use to run your notebook.

### Example

Suppose you have notebookA and notebookB. notebookA contains a cell that has the following Python code:

```
x = 5
```

Even though you did not define x in notebookB, you can access x in notebookB after you run %run notebookA.

```
%run /Users/path/to/notebookA
print(x) # => 5
```

### Relative Paths

To specify a relative path, preface it with ./ or ../. For example, if notebookA and notebookB are in the same directory, you can alternatively run them from a relative path.

```
%run ./notebookA
print(x) # => 5
```

thus

```
%run ../someDirectory/notebookA # up a directory and into another    
print(x) # => 5
```

For more complex interactions between notebooks, see [Notebook Workflows](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html#notebook-workflows).

Comment: Thanks a lot for such detailed answer. I will test the approach before accepting the answer but I believe it will do the work perfectly. I will also have a look at the Notebook Workflows as they seem really useful.

Comment: Jon - No worries, always willing and happy to help. It has worked for me and the data is pulled from the documentation. Hopefully, it solves your problem. Take care.